# How to quickly confront a NumpyArray of string datetimes to a datetime variable inside a Numpy.Where() function

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime

Good day coders,
I have this program where I need to sort a big data set.
This data set contains the following columns:

| Serials | Info_Date | Login_Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| SNXXXXXX | 10/12/2023 12:50 | 14/12/2023 14:30 |
| SNXXXXX1 | 29/02/2024 13:40 | 10/02/2024 10:00 |
| SNXXXXX4 |  | Invalid date |

What I need to do is check if either an **Info_Date** or **Login_date** contains the string `'Invalid date'` or check if the **Info_Date** is older than three months Or if the **Login_Date** is older than thirty days.
In the first case, I used **numpy.where()** and I didn't encounter issues since the data was already in a `string` format but in the other cases I had a big issue since each element of the **NumpyArray** is a string it can't be confronted to a datetime value inside a **numpy.where()**. 
This is the code I used in the first confront scenario:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import time
import numpy as np
source_data = pd.read_excel("./documents/data.xlsx")


three_months_ago = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=90)
thirty_days_ago = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=30)



#Get the values that are "Invalid date"
print(source_data.iloc[
    np.where(source_data["Login_Date"].values == "Invalid date")])
```

I tried converting the data to a `datetime` format by using the `strptime()` function like so:

```
format = str("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
print(np.where(datetime.strptime(source_data["Login_Date"], format) < thirty_days_ago))
```

The expected output should be:

| Serials | Info_Date | Login_Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| SNXXXXX1 | 29/02/2024 13:40 | 10/02/2024 10:00 |

Answer (score 0):

Keep your original dates as strings and make a copy as datetime:

```
# create a copy of the date columns as datetime
tmp = df[['Info_Date', 'Login_Date']].apply(pd.to_datetime,
                                            dayfirst=True, errors='coerce')

today = pd.Timestamp('today')
# Timestamp('2024-03-14 01:23:45.678900')

# is either date invalid?
m1 = df[['Info_Date', 'Login_Date']].eq('Invalid date').any(axis=1)
# is Info_Date older than 3 months?
m2 = tmp['Info_Date'].lt(today-pd.DateOffset(months=3))
# is Login_Date older than 30 days?
m3 = tmp['Login_Date'].rsub(today).gt('30D')

df[['m1', 'm2', 'm3']] = m1, m2, m3
```

Output:

```
    Serials         Info_Date        Login_Date     m1     m2     m3
0  SNXXXXXX  10/12/2023 12:50  14/12/2023 14:30  False  False   True
1  SNXXXXX1  29/02/2024 13:40  10/02/2024 10:00   True  False  False
2  SNXXXXX4               NaN      Invalid date   True   True  False
```

Comment: Do you know how to implement it in a numpy? I need it to be done with numpy since I'm not going to use it with 3 rows of data, but we're talking about sorting 1500 rows and then confronting the results with another 2600 rows in another data set.

Answer (score 0):

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    from datetime import timedelta, date
    from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
    
    # Creating sample data
    data = {
        "Serials": ["SNXXXXXX", "SNXXXXX1", "SNXXXXX4"],
        "Info_Date": ['10/12/2023 12:50', '29/02/2024 13:40',np.nan],
        "Login_Date": ["14/12/2023 14:30", "10/02/2024 10:00", "Invalid date"]
    }
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    
    # create a copy of two columns
    df['Info_Date_test'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Info_Date'], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    df['Login_Date_test'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Login_Date'], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M', errors='coerce').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    
    # if either an Info_Date or Login_date contains the string 'Invalid date'

   df.iloc[np.where((df['Login_Date'] == "Invalid date") | (df['Info_Date'] == "Invalid date"))[0]]
    
    # if the Info_Date is older than three months
    three_months_date = date.today() + relativedelta(months=-3)
    filtered_df = df.iloc[np.where(pd.to_datetime(df['Info_Date_test'])  < pd.to_datetime(three_months_date))[0]]

    # if the Login_Date is older than thirty days.
    thirty_days_date = date.today() + relativedelta(days=-30)
    filtered_df_1 = df.iloc[np.where(pd.to_datetime(df['Login_Date_test'])  < pd.to_datetime(thirty_days_date))[0]]
```

Comment: Do you know how to implement this in a numpy.where() ? I need this to work this way since the amount of data is significantly bigger than these 3 rows, and then afterward I have to confront the found data with 2500 rows in another dataset.
For me using numpy is better since it uses C and will be the fastest. Pandas is still too slow for my needs.

Comment: @Alex I have updated the code please check it.